# Can I check an uploaded file if broken?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

I don't really know how to ask. Can I check that if I'm uploading a file with `HTTP` or with `FTP`. That file how full... Like progress, but not in relatime. I would like to make an automatic file moving script. If a file is full... Uploaded 100%, so not broken. Than my script move that file to another place.

Can I check `completeness of a file` with apache?

My problem is, my users `upload with FTP`. So I `can't make a progress with ajax`.

Comment: With what FTP server?

Comment: I use `proftp` . This is the default of `i-mscp`. I just create users in sql for my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proftpd's [`ExecOnCommand` configuration option](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_exec.html#ExecOnCommand) to run a command whenever a STOR completes successfully. (STOR is the FTP protocol command used to upload a file.) The command will not run if the transfer is aborted. See the [documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_exec.html) for further details.

Comment: ` ExecOnCommand APPE,STOR /path/to/ftp-email-script --user %u --file %f ` This is an example. Is this a terminal command? User means the FTP user? ...What is that e-mail script?

Comment: ExecOnExit is more friendly for me. When someone exited he/she completed the FTP thing... I thing..

Comment: It sounds like you're a bit over your head here. You may want to hire a system administrator.

Comment: Why would you do that? Suppose they canceled their upload halfway through. Then if you used `ExecOnExit` you would process a bad file.

Comment: Yeah.. :-) It would be great to have an admin... You are right, they can cancel uploads... (I don't understood this sentence: you're a bit over your head here)... I'm sorry, I just never used thing like these.

Comment: "In over your head" is an idiom which means [you have undertaken a task for which you aren't fully prepared](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38103/24656).